# Configure GlassFish EJB timeouts

Tags: java, glassfish, timeout, client, ejb

I'm looking around the web to find a way to set timeouts on GlassFish. I'm developing a standalone Java client for GlassFish using EJB's and SessionBean.

I'd like to set some timeouts when I use my remote session because if the server on the other side is done, it takes a while before returning the exception.

So my question is: how can I return an exception after a timeout through the remote session in my Java client? And can I also set a timeout for the lookup?

EDIT: also, is there a way to add kind of listeners to detect when the remote server go down?